# I am trying to find the JAVA_HOME path

Tags: java-home

I ran echo %JAVA_HOME% to find my path. I know it is the wrong path but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Cynthia>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.0.60_33\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.0.60_33\%JAVA_HOME%\bin\bin\bin

C:\Users\Cynthia>
```

Answer (score 4):

On windows, right-click "my computer" and choose "properties.
Go to: "advanced system settings" and then to "environment variables":

[image]

Then go over the variables and set %JAVA_HOME%:

[image]

like this:

[image]

Here's another [helpful link](http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/1.1/docs/setting-java-home.html)

Comment: @alfasin or davidfransis I'm confused again? Do not put the % in the user variable or the system variable. How do I attach a file for you to see mmy variables?

Comment: in the question body, use the image icon in order to upload a picture.

Comment: I made the changes but in the image you see that it caznnot find JAVA_HOME I need this for RED5

Comment: Try adding the path to "jave home" in the `PATH` variable (separated by semicolon `;`)

Comment: This is my path now C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ANT\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\

Comment: looks fine, I would add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33`  (without the `bin`) too.

Comment: I added as you suggested, on my cmd line I type %JAVA_HOME% C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file  or JAVA_HOME get returned 'JAVA_HOME is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Please advise

Comment: @slickery89 create a new file in notepad: line 1 `@ECHO off` and line 2:
`echo %JAVA_HOME%` save it as 1.bat and run it from command prompt

Comment: results When I execute command prompt I'm presented with C:\Users\Cynthia doesn't recognize my 1.bat then I cd C:\1.bat I get C:\Program Files\Java

Comment: run `cd c:` and only then run `1.bat`

Comment: cd c: takes me to C:\Users\Cynthia then run 1.bat not recognized

Comment: @slickery89 run `cd c:\ ` and then `1.bat`

Comment: @alfasin I cd C:/ then at C:\1.bat then it returns on the next line C:\Program Files\Java

Comment: right, and that shows you that JAVA_HOME variable is defined!

Comment: btw, if you manually run from prompt: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` you should also get: `C:\Program Files\Java`