# Trying to use Apache Daemon jsvc

Tags: java, jsvc

I am trying to run a Java program by using jsvc.

I have installed it by

```
sudo apt-get install jsvc.
```

To find out a solution, I tried to read the Apache documentation about it (at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html). But this command:

```
./jsvc -cp commons-daemon.jar:my.jar MyClass
```

and this other:

```
./jsvc -cp my.jar MyClass
```

did not work (of course, I replace the terms by the name of my class etc.).

It gives me the error:

```
bash: ./jsvc: no such file or directory of this type
```

So I use jsvc without "./". And I saw here: [How to start tomcat with jsvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136348/how-to-start-tomcat-with-jsvc) that I should use /usr/bin/jsvc

But an other problem is when I use

```
/usr/bin/jsvc -cp path/to/my/.jar path/to/my/class
```

nothing happens.

I try the link: [How to convert a java program to daemon with jsvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687159/how-to-convert-a-java-program-to-daemon-with-jsvc). But there is something I don’t understand: for the "CLASS =", have I to put a .Main file ? And do I have to put the extension name of the file (for the class and the .jar) ?

I decided to put the .java file which contains my main class (once I putted the .jar, then I didn’t). Then I copied the code, and when I write "esac" and pressed the enter key in the Ubuntu console, the console closed up, and then…nothing.

Has someone already encountered this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your java installation is in /usr/java?
Beside this, in the second command there's the directory missing. You should do something like that:

```
export JAVA_HOME=path/to/java/home
./configure
```

If you don't know where your java installation is located, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117398/java-home-directory) if you are on a mac/*nix, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442330/i-am-trying-to-find-the-java-home-path) if you have windows.

Comment: Yes, I am sure my Java is not in /usr/java, I found links (http://serverfault.com/questions/143786/how-to-determine-java-home-on-debian-ubuntu) to see where is my Java. But it is not the question.